# How to securely auto-mount encrypted drive on SSH login?

Tags: ssh, luks

I successfully followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/709653) guide to create an encrypted drive and have it mounted on login with a `gnome` session.

However, I can't get it to automatically mount when I log in via SSH. Is this possible?

I have no problem connecting to the server via SSH and the encrypted home is correctly mounted on SSH log in. The issue only concerns automatic mount of an encrypted external drive.

Comment: I need more info.  the linked guide has clues on multiple ways of achieving it; one I noted would work from gui or ssh.login, another would only work if login had been made via gui  as you say happens. 
 me I use the `/etc/fstab` solution that requires password @ boot & then works for either login (ssh or gui)

Comment: thanks for your reply... the procedure i linked is the one by `tryion`, in which an encrypted partition is created and set automount using the 'Disks' GUI application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH is allowing remote connections only after a local login to the server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/882303/ssh-is-allowing-remote-connections-only-after-a-local-login-to-the-server)

Comment: @SpasSpasov: thanks, but I edited the question explaining why it does not seem the same issue you linked...

Comment: these command let me mount the encrypted drive when connecting via SSH: `udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb1 && udisksctl mount -b /dev/mapper/luks-bla-bla-bla` ... but i have to insert the root password 3 times!!

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be done, but you can unlock a locked drive over SSH with the following command:

sudo udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda1

This command unlocks the /dev/sda1 drive. Your drive will have it's own name. You will then be prompted for a password, and then get a message like the following:

Unlocked /dev/sda1 as /dev/dm-0.

Now you need the mount point, which can be found with the following:

df -h

Which should give you as one of it's lines as the following:

/dev/dm-0      ext4      7.3T   93M  6.9T   1% /media/nas/Extend-1

cd /media/nas/Extend-1   This will get you into the mounted drive.
To unmount the drive do the following:

sudo udisksctl unmount -b /dev/dm-0

You should get the following message:

Unmounted /dev/dm-0.

This can be done in the terminal, and over SSH, which is the easiest way to mount and unmount a secure drive over SSH that I know of.